# Trying to access Cisco Meraki website with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to create a (initially) very simple CasperJS script to access Cisco Meraki's web site ( https://account.meraki.com/login/dashboard_login?go= ) but no success at all. In fact, even the first start method does not work, and I would really appreciate some help.

The initial capture was showing a grey screen only.I included the waitForText method and got a timeout. Then I included this getHTML to see what was being received, and for my surprise, this is what was shown, instead of the page itself:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I tried also to trace on Chrome what was being accessed, but I didn't succeed on mapping the problem.

Please note I'm passing user and password info on the command line, but this strange behavior is even before that, on the initial page.

The entire script output with its cli.

```
casperjs  --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --cookies-file=cookies.txt meraki.js “username@xxx.xxx”  “password” 
timeout waiting por Text
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

The simple script itself:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.options.waitTimeout = 5000;

var user = casper.cli.get(0);
var pass = casper.cli.get(1);


if (user === undefined) 
{
   console.log("Missing argument: username");
   casper.exit(0);
};

if (pass === undefined) 
{
    console.log("Missing argument: password");
    casper.exit(0);
};

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.on("resource.error", function(resourceError){
    console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
    console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36');
casper.start('https://account.meraki.com/login/dashboard_login?go=');
casper.viewport(1200, 1200);


casper.waitForText("2015 Cisco Systems, Inc.",function (){
    casper.capture('Initial.png');
},function () {
    console.log ("timeout waiting por Text");},10000);

casper.then(function () {
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problems. Your script loads the page for PhantomJS v1.9.8 and v2.0.0 without any additional commandline options (no ignore or protocol). I needed to add those additional commandline options for v1.9.7, but then it worked.

Comment: I was (yes, was) having the issue on a mac running phantomJS 2.0.1-dev and CasperJS 1.0.4.  Started an ubuntu VM running the same phantomJS 2.0.1-dev but CasperJS 1.1.0-dev3 and it worked OK. I tried then to uninstall CasperJS 1.0.4 and install 1.1.0 on the Mac and then it worked perfectly. Thank you for your comments. That helped.